# PHP to jQuery - catching the json

Tags: php, jquery, json

Here's what I want to do. User submits form (a single text input) and send to PHP. PHP returns this;

```
{"status":"true","custid":"00001","custname":"John"}
```

I know that it is in JSON format, but I don't know how to catch and use the value so I can us the returned values.

```
$(function(){
$('#icnumber-form').submit(function(){       

    var icno  = $('#icnumber').val();
    var purl  = 'php/create_process.php'

    $.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : purl,
        cache   : false,
        data    : icno,
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(response){
            var json = $.parseJSON(response);
            alert(json.message);
        },           
        beforeSend:function(){
            $('.cust-exist-view').show();
            }
    });
    return false;

})
});
```

Comment: Nope. Not even the alert came out.

Answer (score 1):

Since you set the dataType to `json`, the response comes back as an already parsed object, so you don't try to parse it yourself.

```
    success : function(response){
        alert(response.status);
    },
```

Comment: It's not working. Removed the parse. Still no alert of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use var `json = $.parseJSON(response);` because jQuery automatically parse the JSON string to object . Just use it as a javascript object to access the json properties. I create a simple demo from your code. [View it in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/QsHw4/)

**JS Code:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#icnumber-form').submit(function () {

        //var icno = $('#icnumber').val();
        var purl = '/echo/json/'

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: purl,
            cache: false,
            data: {
                json: '{"status":"true","custid":"00001","custname":"John"}',
                delay: 1
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                alert( "status:" + response.status
                      + "\ncustname:"+response.custname
                      + "\ncustid:"+ response.custid);
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                // $('.cust-exist-view').show();
            }
        });
        return false;

    })
});
```

**SO you just need to view this part to see how to use json return :**

```
success: function (response) {
                alert( "status:" + response.status //access status
                      + "\ncustname:"+response.custname //access custname
                      + "\ncustid:"+ response.custid); // access custid
            },
```

Comment: I really can't understand this. What I want to do is get the data from php, the array. Right now, `data: icno` is the data sent to server, right? The problem is, I receive the json correctly, just how to catch it?

Comment: In jsfiddle I just simulate the php response for testing. In your code, you just need to care about `function success` that I access to Json properties

Comment: Isn't that because you declare the data in `data` ? I've tried the code but it doesn't work.

Comment: you just need to change the success function in your code. don't need to change any thing else.

Comment: I did. It just didn't work I don't know why...I've even put the header `header("Content-Type: application/json", true);` inside my PHP.

Comment: can you use the firebug to check your request status and response ? And also post your php source code. I will help you to find problem.

Comment: I have found the problem already. Instead of data:icno, the syntax should be data:{icnumber:icno}. Thanks for your help @JamesN

Comment: oh yeah. congratulation !

Comment: if you're satisfy with my answer. pls access it.

Comment: What do you mean access? Your answer didn't explain correctly what I'm missing, but I really appreciate the time you took to respond to my problem. Thanks!